# How to remove or change attribute "title" for button .btn.btn-outline-secondary bootstrap-show-password?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I have enabled tooltips `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` and added a plugin for bootstrap-show-password. I also need to remove or change the default tooltip which is shown after hovering over eye icon.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $but = $(".form-group .input-group-append .btn-outline-secondary");
    $but.mouseover(function(e){   
      e.preventDefault();    
      $(this).removeAttr('title');
    });
  });
</script>
```